# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la URL completa de un archivo subido a s3 con Laravel?

Tags: laravel, aws, amazon-s3

Tengo esto para subir unas imágenes a un `bucket` de `s3`

```
$image = $picture;
$ext = explode(";", explode("/",explode(",", $image)[0])[1])[0];
$image = str_replace('data:image/'.$ext.';base64,', '', $image);
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
$imageName = str_random(10) . '.' . $ext;
$fullImagePath = 'datasheets/' . $imageName;
Storage::disk('s3')->put($fullImagePath, base64_decode($image));

$DataSheetPicture = new DataSheetPicture();
$DataSheetPicture->data_sheet_id = $DataSheet->id;
$DataSheetPicture->picture = Storage::disk('s3')->url($fullImagePath);
$DataSheetPicture->save();
```

El cual me funciona a la perfección, me sube las imágenes correctamente el `bucket`, pero en esta línea:

```
$DataSheetPicture->picture = Storage::disk('s3')->url($fullImagePath);
```

Me guarda en la base de datos la `URL` de la siguiente manera

> /datasheets/6GcfzgUPrA.jpeg
>   /datasheets/AuqHmu8p0W.jpeg

Y yo necesito que me lo devuelva completo así:

> https://s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/BUCKET-NAME/FULL-IMAGE-PATH

No quiero quemar la región ni los nombres de los `buckets` ya que pueden variar según el entorno que se esté utilizando y no me quedaría dinámico

Answer (score -1):

lo que colocas como primer parametro es en donde lo subes a tu dominio de s3, simplemente lo concatenas.

$fullImagePath = '/path/imagen/a/subir/imagen.png';

Storage::disk('s3')
->put('BUCKET-NAME/FULL-IMAGE-PATH.png', file_get_contents($fullImagePath));

https://s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/BUCKET-NAME/FULL-IMAGE-PATH